# Swift Convert from CoreData to CoreLocation - having some issues

Tags: swift, core-data, core-location

I have a fairly simple project where I need to store an array of CLLocations to a CoreData file to an object(Location that stores the Latitude, Longitude and the timestamp.

Going from CoreLocation to Location is pretty straightforward.
The reverse of this is not straightforward as I get this error message.
"cannot assign to property: 'timestamp' is a get-only property" when I do this

```
 func changeLocationToCLLocation(place: Location){
        let clLocation = CLLocation(latitude: place.longitude, longitude: place.latitude)
        clLocation.timestamp = place.timeAtLocation
    }
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
 let clLocation = CLLocation(latitude: place.longitude, longitude: place.latitude)
```

You're using the wrong initializer. Use this one:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocation/1423666-init

It's more work but it lets you set the timestamp.